# I'm facing to install the Calabash Sandbox

Tags: ruby, calabash, xamarin.mac

```
Admins-Mac-mini:~ admin$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/calabash/install/master/install-osx.sh | bash
Preparing Ruby 2.1.6-p336...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Installing gems, this may take a little while...
##########                                                                14.8%
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
[CalabashGems.zip]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of CalabashGems.zip or
CalabashGems.zip.zip, and cannot find CalabashGems.zip.ZIP, period.
Preparing sandbox...
```

################################################################## 100.0%

```
Done! Installed:`enter code here`
calabash-ios: bash: line 1: `calabash-ios`: command not found
calabash-android bash: line 1: calabash-android: command not found
xamarin-test-cloud: bash: line 1: test-cloud: command not found
Execute 'calabash-sandbox update' to check for gem updates.
Execute 'calabash-sandbox' to get started!
```

can any one help out me with installation of calabash-sandbox

Comment: Calabash is a Ruby testing framework, so in that regard this is on-topic.

Comment: Hi Wayne Conrad, ya regarding ruby testing framework. Thank you